# understand structure and meaning of noun phrase

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns, clauses

> Need recognition occurs when an individual senses a difference between **what he or she perceives to be the ideal** versus the actual state of affairs.

I bolded the noun phrase "*what her or she perceives to be the ideal*".

I understand **what** will serve as the object of **perceives** ,
and I am guessing that the infinitive **to be the ideal** is a object complement instead of a purpose adjunct.
 So in the example sentence , since **what** is understood to be between "perceives" and "the infinitive clause(to be the ideal)" ,**to be the ideal** will be the complement of **what**.

Which means that the noun phrase can be interpreted as :
He or she perceives **what**, and **what** is the ideal .

Is my understanding above correct?

Comment: No: object complements can only be AdjPs and NPs, not clauses. "To be the ideal" is an infinitival relative clause modifying the object of "perceives", i.e. 'gap'.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for the answer, the infinitive clause "to be the ideal" will be adjectival and modifies the "gap" , and the gap represents "what", is this correct?

Comment: And I found this website (https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Object-Complements.htm) when I started learning complements, it says that infinitive can be complements , is the information from that website reliable?

Comment: Yes, it's completely wrong. The infinitival in your example is a relative clause.

Comment: *Between* and *versus* should not be combined. It should either be *X versus Y* or *between X and Y*. But *between X **versus** Y* is wrong.

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks, the sentence is from my textbook, but I am not sure if it is written my native speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Need recognition occurs when an individual senses a difference between*
>   [*what he or she perceives ____ to be the ideal versus the actual state of*
>   *affairs*].

The bracketed element is a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative clause where "what" means "that which". "What" thus serves simultaneously as head of the whole NP and object of "perceives", and is represented in the relative clause by the '____' notation, called 'gap'.

The variables can be represented as "he or she perceives *x*; *x* could be the ideal ...".

The clause *to be the ideal versus the actual state of affairs* is an infinitival  relative clause modifying 'gap'.